# How do you set an ArrayList of integers[] equal to an ArrayList of doubles[]

Tags: java

How do you set an ArrayList of integers[] equal to an ArrayList of doubles[]?

I tried a lot of different things but none of them worked.  I'm sure there is a really simple answer to this problem but I could not find it on google thanks.

Im coding in Java

I tried this

```
drawablerect =  (ArrayList int[]) rect;
```

And setting each array in drawables to each array in rect.

drawablerect is an ArrayList of int[] and rect is a ArrayList of double[]

This is what I did

```
for(int i = 0; i < rect.size(); i++)
       for(int index = 0; index < 7; index++)
                 drawablerect.get(i)[index] = (int) rect.get(i)[index];
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Show us what you have tried, and we might be able to help.

Comment: I have a disease, I can't see bold letters. Now where is the question?

Comment: How do you set an ArrayList of integers[] equal to an ArrayList of doubles[]?

Comment: what type is `drawablerect` and what type is `rect`? Try to make your examples [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), either you'll find the answer when trying to write it or get a quick answer from us. It's hard to answer question when we don't have enough information.

Comment: drawablerect is an ArrayList of int[] and rect is a ArrayList of double[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an integer of the appropriate size
2. Iterate over the ArrayList
3. Assign each value to the array

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution:

```
// Beware of precision loss (0.99999 --> 0)
public static List<int[]> toListIntArray(List<double[]> input) {
    List<int[]> output = new ArrayList<>(input.size());
    for (double[] in : input) {
        int[] ints = new int[in.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
            ints[i] = (int) in[i];
        }
        output.add(ints);
    }
    return output;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
drawablerect = toListIntArray(rect);
```